# How do you call a method within the same activity

Tags: android, methods, parameters

I've been fiddling around with sample codes and ran across a snippet and tried using it but problem is I don't know how to call this kind of method from the same activity I declared it in. The snippet only showed this kind of method and not how to call it. I don't even know what this is defined as so it's been hard finding the answer, a method with multiple parameters I guess?

This is the method I want to call, it's linked to another class `Payments`.

```
 void Calculate(Context con, Payments Pay)
```

I've tried the usual `Calculate()` but it tells me that `Calculate(Context,Payments) cannot be applied to ();`

Can anyone explain what's going on ?

Comment: you need tp pass the expected params

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_syntax.htm

Comment: Not to be rude but you should learn basic Java before tackling Android. Otherwise, it could be a scary world

Comment: [By convention, method names should start with a lower case letter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate an object of the class Payments:

`Payments pay = New Payment(Paramters);`

Then call calculate with the getApplicationContext and the Payment object:

`Calculate(getApplicationContext(), pay);`

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass context means activity instance & instance of payment class

Like

```
       Context con = getActivity();
       Payments Pay = new Payments();
       Calculate(con,pay);
       //removed the "void"
```

I hope this help you